# FATAL org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - error parsing conf file: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: osx-lion, apache-pig, homebrew

I'm trying to run pig locally, installed using homebrew, to test a script. However, I get the following error when I attempt to run a simple dump from the interactive prompt `pig -x local`:

```
2012-07-16 23:20:40,447 [Thread-7] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
[Fatal Error] :63:85: Character reference "&#2" is an invalid XML character.
2012-07-16 23:20:40,688 [Thread-7] FATAL org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - error parsing conf file: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#2" is an invalid XML character.
```

The same load/dump works fine on Elastic MapReduce.

I can't find any XML config files, and I've tried with both version 0.9.2 and 0.10.0

What am I missing?

Edit: Just checked a direct download (vs. homebrew) and it doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked out what the problem was. I ended up having to use `dtruss -p` on the pig/java process. This revealed a temporary directory and dynamically generated xml files. Once the temporary directory was discovered, it all fell quickly into place.

It was picking up the proxy excludes from my network connections, which had, as far as I can tell, `&#2` (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02/index.htm) embedded in it. How this invalid value came to be in my network preferences in the first place, I haven't the faintest clue.

The value was then being pulled into dynamically generated files, for example `/tmp/hadoop-vertis/mapred/staging/vertis-1005847898/.staging/job_local_0001/job.xml`.

The offending lines:

```
<property><name>ftp.nonProxyHosts</name><value>localhost|*.localhost|127.0.0.1|h&#2;|*.h&#2;</value></property>
<property><name>socksNonProxyHosts</name><value>localhost|*.localhost|127.0.0.1|h&#2;|*.h&#2;</value></property>
<property><name>http.nonProxyHosts</name><value>localhost|*.localhost|127.0.0.1|h&#2;|*.h&#2;</value></property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your Hadoop configuration files have correct configuration data.

Have a look in your hadoop/conf directory.

Have a look inside:

hdfs-site.xml
mapred-site.xml
core-site.xml

Comment: I did not have hadoop installed. My understanding was that this wasn't required for pig -x local. I have subsequently installed hadoop, but this doesn't seem to have made a difference.